# How to read variable from a yaml file into a salt-states (sls) file (Salt-stack)?

Tags: yaml, salt-stack

I have an `config.yaml` file that defines some variables:

```
#config/product1/config.yaml
var_one: "url_1"
var_two: "url_2"
```

How can I read this file in a `download.sls` file so that I can download files to `/local/downloaded_files/` using URL's stored in `config.yaml`?

I went through the [`salt-states` document](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.yaml.html) but it's very lacking on implementation examples with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [`import_yaml`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html) in the following sort of fashion

```
# File: download.sls
#
# import your yaml data ...
{% import_yaml "config/product1/config.yaml" as config %}

# now you can use it ...
{{ config.var_one }}
```

Note that you can also use `load_yaml` if you would like to define your data using `yaml` inline **within** the state file itself

```
{% load_yaml as config %}
var_one: "url_1"
var_two: "url_2"
{% endload %}

{{ config.var_one }}
```